# React Native assembleRelease fails with an Exception. Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative68DebugKotlin'

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have trouble with assembleRelease after updating the packages in my React Native app. The execution goes to 99% and fails with the following error message

[image]

However the assembleDebug is working fine

After the update,

- "react": "^17.0.2"
- "react-native": "^0.67.3"
- "react-native-navigation": "^7.26.0"

The Kotlin version I'm using in build.gradle is **1.6.0**.
Upgrading or downgrading it did not work